# Create bool value which is neither true or false

Tags: c#

Disclaimer: It's not about `Nullable<bool>` or something.

I've seen someone created a bool value which was neither `true` or `false`. It was an example why exhaustive match is not possible in C#. Unfortunately, I've lost source code with an example, which I'd really like to restore.

So the question is: how to make `default` arm to be called in the following code?

```
bool b = GetMyWeirdBool()
switch (b)
{
   case true: Console.WriteLine("true"); break;
   case false: Console.WriteLine("false"); break;
   default: Console.WriteLine("neither o_0"); break;
}
```

IIRC there was some dirty hacking via `Marshal` or `StructLayout` or something.

Comment: When you ask questions like this where _someone created a bool which was neither true or false_ it is best to also add a link where you get that info.

Comment: @Steve If i have it i won't ask it, sorry. I don't actually have source code of it, I just remember that when I pasted it in linqpad it actually ran `default` arm. So it's defenitly possible, the only question is what exactly code have to be written.

Comment: As far I know, `bool` will always hold either `true` or `false`

Comment: @bharadwaj booleans don't exist in iL. Just zero Vs non-zero integers

Comment: @MarcGravell so, is it possible to have other than boolean value though `c#` code?

Comment: `byte val = anynumber;` then `bool something = *(bool*)&val;` works in unsafe context. but anything other than 0 prints true.

Comment: @Bharadwaj yes; my answer has three different ways, but they all do something slightly evil :)

Comment: @MarcGravell Yep, got it by debugging, weird.

Comment: What is a valid use case for this?

Comment: Why not just use an enum with values of true, false and unknown?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably a true with a value of 43 or similar. The point is: `Boolean` is a lie - it doesn't exist at the IL level. It is simply an integer with a value that is zero or non-zero. That works fine for the "brtrue" and "brfalse" opcodes for any boolean values (1,-1 or 42) - the problem comes when you do an equality test between two values that are meant to be booleans: a "ceq" opcode will fail for two true booleans that aren't actually equal. Likewise, a "switch" opcode (jump-table - commonly used for `switch` in C#) will fail if the values aren't what the compiler expected.

This may confuse some APIs, returning false on equality to another true value, but reporting true when compared via brtrue.

Via `unsafe` code treating an `int` as a `bool`:

```
static unsafe bool GetMyWeirdBool()
{
    int i = 42;
    return *(bool*)(&i);
}
```

via IL:

```
static bool GetMyWeirdBool()
{
    var method = new DynamicMethod("evil", typeof(bool), null);
    var il = method.GetILGenerator();
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, 42);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    var func = (Func<bool>)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<bool>));
    return func();
}
```

via a `struct` with overlapped fields:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
struct Evil
{
    public Evil(int value)
    {
        Boolean = false;
        Int32 = value;
    }
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public bool Boolean;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public int Int32;

}
static bool GetMyWeirdBool()
{
    var val = new Evil(42);
    return val.Boolean;
}
```

Comment: Yep, I believe it was struct `int + bool + FieldOffset(0)` combination

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy anything that treats an int as a bool will work; there's at least 3 ways I can think of - `unsafe`, `StructLayout` or IL-emit

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy examples of all 3 added

Comment: I bow my head to you Marc, I thought that was not possible

Comment: what is the exact usage of this?

Comment: @MarcGravell isn't it UB?

Comment: @Bharadwaj you are just breaking the rules, no real usage.

Comment: @Bharadwaj you're not meant to do it; it is just something that is technically legal :)

Comment: so how to use it? I assigned your method to my bool like `Clicked = GetMyWeirdBool();`  but it returned "true". How could I use your method?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a struct with explicit layout:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct NotBool
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public readonly bool Value;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private readonly int Int;

    public NotBool(int intValue)
    {
        Value = false;
        Int = intValue;
    }
}
```

Test:

```
NotBool notBool = new NotBool(255);
switch (notBool.Value)
{
    case true:
        break;
    case false:
        break;
    default:
        Debug.WriteLine("Default");
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

this seems to work for me. you get ton of neither's.

```
unsafe
{
    for (int i = 0; i < byte.MaxValue; i++)
    {
        byte val = (byte)i;
        bool b = *(bool*)&val;

        switch (b)
        {
            case true: Console.WriteLine("true"); break;
            case false: Console.WriteLine("false"); break;
            default: Console.WriteLine("neither o_0"); break;
        }
    }
}
```

But notice that these Booleans evaluate to ture in if statement. at least for me, anything other than 0 evaluates true.

<s>even comparisons like `b == true`</s>  that turns out to be compiler optimization. `b == x` where `x` is true and `b` is any value doesn't evaluate to true.

Comment: "But notice that these Booleans evaluate to ture in if statement. at least for me, anything other than 0 evaluates true." - yes, that's because of how `brtrue` is defined: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.brtrue(v=vs.110).aspx - as a side note, this means that tests like `if(expr == 0)`, `if(expr != 0)`, `if(i == null)` and `if(i != null)` can all be done simply via `brtrue` and `brfalse` - it doesn't need a `ldc.i4.0` + `beq` or `ldnull` + `beq`. Testing for zero is cheaper than an equality test.